# 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, strip, data-cleaning

I want to clean one column of my df['emp_length']
[shown in the screen shot][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzBHG.png)

but when I use

```
df_10v['emp_length'] = df_10v['emp_length'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('<').rstrip('+'))
```

to remove thing i dont want. It gave me an error:

```
'float' object has no attribute 'lstrip'
```

However, the type shows object instead of float.
I tried .remove too but gave me the same error. 
I also tried

```
df['column'] = df['column'].astype('str')
```

to change df_10v['emp_length'] in to string and then strip, but it does not work either. Anybody know how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: What does your column look like?

Comment: obviously `x` is a float.

Comment: the column is in the screen shot link, i cant post picture ...

Comment: why x is a float, i thought it is an object...Why is that?

Comment: I don't think your screenshot lines up with the data you're actually working on.  In the screenshot, `emp_length` contains strings, and your `map` transformations will work as expected.  This would be easier to help you with if you post a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE:** removing all non-digits:

```
df_10v['emp_length'] = df_10v['emp_length'].astype(str).str.replace('\D+', '')
```

**old answer:**

IIUC:

```
df_10v['emp_length'] = df_10v['emp_length'].astype(str).str.lstrip('<').str.rstrip('+')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am able to remove the '<' and 'year', but still cant remove '+'. i tried to remove year first and then +, but it does not work.  
                        df_10v['emp_length'] = df_10v['emp_length'].astype(str).str.lstrip('<').str.rstrip('years')
df_10v['emp_length'] = df_10v['emp_length'].astype(str).str.rstrip('+')

Comment: @PumpkinC, please [post in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45825380/edit) a small (3-5 rows)  reproducible data set and your desired data set. Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Comment: for those '10+ years', i cant remove the '+'

Comment: @PumpkinC, are you trying to remove everything except digits?

Comment: Yes. that's what i am trying to do

Comment: @PumpkinC, if you would post a small sample data set and your desired data set - I bet you would have a proper answer within 1-2 minutes...

Comment: got it! thank you! i am kind of new to all this.. still struggling how to ask right question.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. and Thank you for your advice!